# Marklogic : unique words count

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have the following xml structure:-

```
<Root>
<text>
 Marklogic is a good big data tool. Right now I am exploring Marklogic.
</text>
</Root>
```

Now I want to count the occurrence of unique words(e.g Marklogic- 2 times, big- 1 time, data-1 time etc). I achieved this by using `fn:count()` but `fn:count()` is too slow in case of large database.

Is there any other optimized way to achieve this ? (something related to indexes)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403223/counting-all-unique-words-in-an-unstructured-document-using-index-data

Answer (score 0):

Per http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon#chapter you could enable the word-lexicon and use `cts:words`.

Comment: We checked this documentation but didn't find any way to get individual word count. We are able to get all unique words by enabling word lexicon but our purpose is to get word count for those word lexicons. We also tried xdmp:estimate but it return number of fragments. So in above sample XML file we get count "1" for "Marklogic" word which should be "2" because it occurs two time in a fragment. We still stuck please help.

Comment: @PuneetPant You can use the option `item-frequency` to get the element count instead of using `fragment-frequency`, which is the default.